# troubles with converting class into interface

Tags: angular, typescript

trying turn class into interface, because my teacher said it is right way to do.

```
export class Stats {  
  donePomodoros: number;
  doneShortBreaks: number;
  doneLongBreaks: number;

constructor() {
 this.donePomodoros = 0;
 this.doneShortBreaks = 0;
 this.doneLongBreaks = 0;
 }
}
```

but when in service I've turned it into interface got the problem

> 'Stats' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```
  private observableStats: BehaviorSubject<Stats> = new BehaviorSubject(
   new Stats()
  );
```

how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export interface Stats {
 donePomodoros: number;
 doneShortBreaks: number;
 doneLongBreaks: number;
}

 private observableStats: BehaviorSubject<Stats> = new BehaviorSubject(
   {
     donePomodoros: 1,
      doneShortBreaks: 2,
      doneLongBreaks: 3
    }
  );
```

In a nutshell, you can't create interfaces instances directly.
An interface is a group of related properties and methods that describe an object, but neither provides implementation nor initialization for them.